# How to remove duplication in this simple code?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, refactoring, code-duplication

There is a function `AppendLastSlashIfNotExist` I made.
Today, I've decided to make another function `AppendLastBackSlashIfNotExist`

```
wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path)
{
    if (path == L"/")
    {
        return path;
    }

    if (path.size() == 0 || path[path.size() - 1] != L'/')
    {
        return path + L"/";
    }
    return path;
}

wstring AppendLastBackSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path)
{
    if (path == L"\\")
    {
        return path;
    }

    if (path.size() == 0 || path[path.size() - 1] != L'\\')
    {
        return path + L"\\";
    }
    return path;
}
```

Yes, it sucks. Only **Slash** -> **BackSlash** is the change. I wanted to remove duplications.

```
wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path, bool backSlash)
{
    if (path == (backSlash ? L"\\" : L"/"))
    {
        return path;
    }

    if (path.size() == 0 || path[path.size() - 1] != (backSlash ? L'\\' : L'/'))
    {
        return path + (backSlash ? L"\\" : L"/");
    }
    return path;
}
```

I integrated them. Duplication removed. But an additional parameter came. I still feel uncomfortable.
Isn't there other ways to remove duplication? For example, using by high-order function.
Any idea please.

Comment: I guess that you should incorporate the Path class instead of using these functions. In your class path you will make care for validity of your path string. Use OO concept.

Comment: Indicate a default value for `bool backSlash=false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing a boolean to indicate the slash type you could just pass the slash character that is required, and possibly have a default for the slash character:

```
wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path,
                                  wchar_t slash = L'\\')
{
    // This is superfluous and is handled in next if condition.
    /*if (1 == path.length() && path[0] == slash)
    {
        return path;
    }*/

    if (path.size() == 0 || path[path.size() - 1] != slash)
    {
        return path + slash;
    }
    return path;
}

std::wstring s(L"test");
std::wcout << AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(s) << "\n";
std::wcout << AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(s, L'/') << "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

`template` is the answer for such problems:

```
template<char SLASH_TYPE>
wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path)
{
    if (path[0] == SLASH_TYPE)  // <--- comparing char (not const char*)
    {
        return path;
    }

    if (path.size() == 0 || path[path.size() - 1] != SLASH_TYPE)
    {
        return path + SLASH_TYPE;
    }
    return path;
}
```

You need to alter your logic a bit for this purpose, as you see that you are passing `char` and not `const char*` as the template parameter.

The function will be called as:

```
y = AppendLastSlashIfNotExist<'/'>(x);
y = AppendLastSlashIfNotExist<'\\'>(x);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for `path.size() == 0` before comparing `path[0] == SLASH_TYPE` ?

Comment: btw, the logic is not same anymore because of your change. `path[0] == SLASH_TYPE`

Comment: Why not pass the relevant character as a run-time argument? I'm well known to shoot with templates but this seems to be too big a canon to fire. The only reason you might want to make this a template is to avoid binding the char when passing function objects.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to think of the one who reads the code later. A bool is not readable code, but `AppendLastSlashIfNotExists` and `AppendLastBackSlashIfNotExists` is. My suggestion is to keep both of these functions and then from them call the common one.

```
wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExistInternal(__in const wstring& path, bool backSlash)
{
    // as before..
    return path;
}

wstring AppendLastBackSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path){
    return AppendLastSlashIfNotExistInternal(path, true);
}

wstring AppendLastSlashIfNotExist(__in const wstring& path)
{
    return AppendLastSlashIfNotExistInternal(path, false);
}
```

This way, you still keep it readable for the one who later maintains the code

Comment: +1.  Retain the readable function names, but delegate their common behavior to another function.  Personally, I'd pass the character to be appended rather than a boolean, but otherwise this is the approach I would take.

Comment: @CarlManaster I fully agree. Make it as generic as possible

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use a TrimEnd with argument in order to remove all unwanted characters from the end of the string:

```
template<class T> 
T TrimEnd( const T& arg, const T& unwantedCharacters )
{
  // Do manipulations here using stringstream in order to cut unwanted characters.
}
```

or you can avoid using template and use 2 versions of this function with string and wstring arguments.

after that you simply append needed tail of characters on your result string.